# Find a sequence of real-valued nonnegative functions $f_{n}$ on $[0, 1]$ such that $\limsup$ is infinite, but limit of the integral is $0$

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

Seeking a sequence of real-valued nonnegative functions $f_{n}$ on $[0, 1]$ such that $\limsup_{n \to \infty} f_{n}(x) = \infty$ for all $x \in [0, 1]$, and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{[0, 1]} f_{n}(x) dx = 0$.

I've been playing with various things multiplied by characteristic functions, but so far my examples fail one of the conditions. For instance, $\{x^{-1/2} \cdot \chi_{[1/n, 1]}\}$ has infinite limit superior, but the limit of the integral is non-$0$. And multiplying by $\chi_{[1/(n+1), 1/n]}$ will send the function to $0$.

Some kind of hint to shake up my thinking would be appreciated here.

Answer (score 2):

Let $m\in \mathbb{N}$ be arbitrary. For $0\leq i\leq m-1$ let $g_{m,i}$ be the characteristic function of the interval $[(i-1)/m, i/m]$ multiplied by $\log m$.

Then a sequence of functions that solves your problem is as follows:

$$g_{1,1}, g_{2,1}, g_{2,2}, g_{3,1}, g_{3,2}, g_{3,3}, g_{4,1}, \ldots$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Consider

$$f_1 = \chi_{[0,1]}$$
$$f_2 = 2\chi_{\left[0,\frac12\right\rangle}, f_3 = 2\chi_{\left[\frac12, 1\right]}$$
$$f_4 = 3\chi_{\left[0,\frac14\right\rangle}, f_5 = 3\chi_{\left[\frac14,\frac12\right\rangle}, f_6 = 3\chi_{\left[\frac12,\frac34\right\rangle}, f_7 = 3\chi_{\left[\frac34,1\right]}$$
$$\vdots$$

The integral of the functions in the $k$-th row is $\frac{k}{2^{k-1}}$ which goes to $0$ as $k\to\infty$.

Comment: You are right, I messed up the first condition.

Comment: Wow. Impressive. Are there any others?